# Powershell: Trouble getting a list of network printers from a remote computer and installing those printers on a new computer

Tags: powershell, wmi

2 weeks into learning powershell, so explain things slowly.
$oldMachineName would normally be set by the user using Read-host. In the scripts below, I've replaced it with various names to test different scenarios.

My script:

```
$oldPcName = Read-Host "Please enter the name or IP address of the old pc."

$oldNetworkPrinters = Get-WmiObject win32_printer -ComputerName "$oldPcName" 

foreach ($printer in $oldNetworkPrinters)
    {
    $fullPath =$printer.name
    write-host $fullPath
     (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection($fullPath)           
    }
```

The resulting values for $fullPath when I run the script on the old computer, getting its own printer list:

> PDF-XChange 4.0
>
> Microsoft XPS Document Writer
>
> Fax
>
> CutePDF Writer
>
> \PPAS0969I\PPAP_RIVERHOUNDS_PCL
>
> \PPAS0969I\PPAP_HP5KIT_PCL
>
> \PPAS0969I\PPAP_HP5KIT_PS
>
> \PPAS0969I\PPAP_RIVERHOUNDS_PS
>
> \PPAS0969I\ppap_panthers_pcl

The resulting values for $fullPath when I run the script on the new computer, getting the old computer's printer list:

> PDF-XChange 4.0
>
> Microsoft XPS Document Writer
>
> Fax
>
> CutePDF Writer

The resulting values for $fullPath when I run the script on the new computer, getting its own printer list:

> PDF-XChange 4.0
>
> Microsoft XPS Document Writer
>
> Fax

Judging by the presence of CutePDF writer when new computer gets the old list, and the absence of it when new computer gets its own list, I would say the new computer is successfully receiving a list of printers from the old computer. Now, why aren't the network printers included in that list?

Answer (score 2):

Network printers (those that are shared off another server i.e. PPAS0969I) are per-user so when you query `Win32_Printer`, you only see the local printers plus those loaded in your current profile.

To help illustrate, try running the following:

```
gwmi win32_printer | select name,local | ft -a
```